# Returning JButton's to Enabled via separate ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, class, jbutton, actionlistener

I've implemented code that will - amongst other things - make a series of JButton's disabled after being clicked. The code for this is below:

```
ActionListener disableButton = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            if (!(event.getSource() instanceof JButton)) {
                return;
            }
            theModel.currentWord.append(event.getActionCommand());
            wordDisplay.setText(theModel.getCurrentWord());
            ((JButton) event.getSource()).setEnabled(false);
        }
    };
    theModel.randomLetters();
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        dice = new JButton(theModel.letters.get(i));
        dice.addActionListener(disableButton);
        boggleGrid.add(dice);
    }
```

Notice the "((JButton)event.getSource()).setEnabled(false);" line. This, after completing the previous lines, makes any clicks on the button inactionable. I wish to reverse this when a seperate button is clicked. It's code is below:

```
JButton submitWordButton = new JButton("Submit Word");
    submitWordButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent submit) {
            wordDisplay.setText("");
            theModel.currentWord.delete(0, 16);
            ((JButton) submit.getSource()).setEnabled(true);
        }
    });
    info.add(submitWordButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

My dilemma is I don't know how to reference the JButton's outside of the ActionListener that disables them once clicked and hence enabled them again. The button I want to use to do this (the one with code most recently pasted above) is in another class. Any ideas?

Comment: Build a `List` or array which contains all the `JButton`s, then simply loop through them and re-enable them when you need to

Comment: declare a JButton object reference (variable) outside of the methods (global for class) then you can access it

Comment: So there isn't a way to reference the JButtons within the other ActionListener?

Comment: @SemicolonCapitalD Not without some kind of class instance field first, not really

Comment: as @MadProgrammer mentioned, inside the ActionListener you will have reference on the action source only not other objects unless they are accessible instances from within the `actionPerformed()`